# cannot connect to mysql on remote server

Tags: magento2, database, data-migration, access

I am trying to migrate data from magento 1 to maganto 2. Both sites are on different server. So when I try to migrate by below command :

> sudo php /var/www/m2.gocleaning.nl/bin/magento migrate:settings -r
>   /var/www/siteurl/vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.3.7/config.xml

it is showing error in the image. 
[image: Error]

FYI : I also can't connect to mysql remotely by using

```
mysql -u remote -h 176.9.9.14 -p
```

It is also giving connection timed out error.
Tried this solution : [Link](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-connect-to-your-database-remotely/)

One thing I want to confirm should I have to grant privleges on remote database or on local database?

Please help me to sort out this issue ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you ran out of space on your MySQL partition. Check your utilization and allocate some memory.

Comment: on the same server it is working fine but when i try to access from another server it is giving error

Comment: on it's own server it is working fine but when i try to access from another server it is giving error

Comment: user name and password correct? Also, does the user have correct privileges?

Comment: One thing I want to confirm that if I want to access m1 db from another server then where I have to run grant privilege command. And what will be the user name to grant.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't access your remote MySQL server using the console command, the remote server might not have remote access enabled.

Please check this answer for details -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31897406/pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-timed-out-on-my-local-computer

Comment: I have tried all the steps given in your link but no luck

Comment: is there any logs that will provide me why I can't access remote database

Comment: Did you check the firewalls between both server? Is a tcp connection for the port you are using allowed? For database logs location and if logging is enabled check the configuration of MySQL.

Comment: Just to get sure: the my.cnf file of your remote server contains the lines  `bind-address    = 176.9.9.14` and `# skip-networking` (this one either commented out or removed)

Comment: bind-address should be on 176.9.9.14 server or other server.

Comment: and in which database I have to grant privileges on server 1 or server2 if I want to access server1's database from server2.

Comment: the MySQL configuration mentioned above have to be on the server you are trying to connect to, i.e. the server which listens to the ip address 176.9.9.14 (I don't now which one is 1 or 2 for you). On that servers database you have to grant privileges for your user and the ip from which you try to connect.

Answer (score 0):

If this question is not related with migration and to set up a remote MySql database for Magento 2, you must follow the guideline documentation given by Magento here.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/mysql_remote.html